# Lambda and vectorize in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I'm learning data analysis while performing vectorized operation with lambda function it run at first but again run it shows error as `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

sample data of tips.csv file

[image]

```
quality = lambda x:'Generous' if x['tip']/x['total_bill']>0.25 else 'Other'
```

[image]

This is the image that I run first which doesn't show any error

```
a = np.vectorize(quality)
df['q2'] = a(df['total_bill'],df['tip'])
df['q1'] = np.vectorize(quality)(df['total_bill'],df['tip'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize solution different way - with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead lambda and `np.vectorize`:

```
df['q1'] = np.where(df['tip']/df['total_bill']>0.25, 'Generous' ,'Other')
```

EDIT:

After some research for correct working need pass `x, y` to lambda and also change selecting by columns in `lambda function` like, because you pass 2 columns to function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tip':[1,2,6],
    'total_bill':[1,5,1]  })

quality = lambda x, y:'Generous' if x/y>0.25 else 'Other'

a = np.vectorize(quality)
df['q2'] = a(df['total_bill'],df['tip'])
df['q1'] = np.vectorize(quality)(df['total_bill'],df['tip'])
print (df)

   tip  total_bill        q2        q1
0    1           1  Generous  Generous
1    2           5  Generous  Generous
2    6           1     Other     Other
```

Comment: Getting answer is not the problem. I just want to know why it's not working now but worked before. This answer is quite great. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Deepan - Unfortuantely not idea.